# cant get particular data from session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller:logic part

```
        $query1['shipping']=$this->cart_model->get_shipping_info();

        $query2['pay']=$this->cart_model->get_payment_info();

        $query1=$this->session->set_userdata($query1);

        $query2=$this->session->set_userdata($query2);
```

Model:fetch data from database

```
  public function get_shipping_info()
    {
     $query=$this->db->query('select * from shipping;');
     return $query->result();
    }
  public function get_payment_info()
    {
     $query=$this->db->query('select * from payment;');
     return $query->result();
    }
```

View:here goes the view that i want to show to user

```
        print_r($this->session->userdata('shipping'));
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        print_r($this->session->userdata('pay'));
```

Comment: have you tried to print variables at every step? What result did you get?

Comment: yes i print these data in view.

Comment: for $query1 i get this value Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [s_id] => 12 [u_id] => 1 [full_name] => hamza [email] => hamzaraper99@yahoo.com [address] => manikdee.dhaka [mobile] => 01547869845 [city] => dhaka [country] => BANGLADESH ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [s_id] => 13 [u_id] => 1 [full_name] => asif [email] => asif@yahoo.com [address] => banasree,dhaka [mobile] => 01547869465 [city] => dhaka [country] => BANGLADESH ) )

Comment: i want to get the [s_id] data but i couldnt get it yet?what to do now?

Comment: `$a[] = $this->session->userdata('shipping'); echo $a->s_id;`

Comment: nana partykar i use your code bt it shows me this-:Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: you have a limit in the session space, is better to use a **limit** or **where** in your `get_shipping_info` and `get_payment_info` model, coz you will get alot of rows

Comment: how to use limit?help me to get rid of.

Comment: if you have the id or other value from `shipping & pay` tables send it to the model or make this `$this->db->limit(1); $this->db->get('table')->row();` Because if you don´t limit the result, you can get as many result as you have in your table and you have a limit space in session part

Answer (score 0):

Depends if you auto-load the session library or not, we will need to include session library:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Then you able to get session :

```
$session_id = $this->session->userdata('SessionID');
```

And still can't get then try to store array instead of stdClass Object.

Does this get you what you need?

Comment: i load library in autoload.php.but still dont get session particular data that i wanted.this data also saved in database but cant get that in view.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting session like this `'shipping'` and `'pay'`. But **in your session there is no variable created for this**.

```
$newdata = array(
    'shipping'  => 'shipping_123',
    'pay'     => 'pay_456'
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

and to retrive the session you can use

```
echo($this->session->userdata('shipping')); # Outputs shipping_123
echo($this->session->userdata('pay')); # Outputs pay_456
```

---

> ***While looking your code, I think you need to pass data from controller to view. If true mention it too***

---

Read this

1. [Session Library - Codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: passing data is necessary for session?i knew that i can use session data from antwhere.!!!

Comment: @walidalam Try to add session array first. the set the session like i hve shown to you

Comment: Array ( [shipping] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [s_id] => 12 [u_id] => 1 [full_name] => hamza [email] => hamzaraper99@yahoo.com [address] => manikdee.dhaka [mobile] => 01547869845 [city] => dhaka [country] => BANGLADESH ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [s_id] => 13 [u_id] => 1 [full_name] => asif [email] => asif@yahoo.com [address] => banasree,dhaka [mobile] => 01547869465 [city] => dhaka [country] => BANGLADESH ) ) ) ---------how to get that s_id  and print it in view?

Comment: with session or normal passing data??

Comment: `$newdata = array(
    'shipping'  => 'shipping_123',
    'shipping_s_id'     => $query1['shipping'][0]['s_id']
);` try like this

Comment: @walidalam **I suggest you to use normal data pass to view and only set common values in the session**

Comment: @walidalam if answer helpful acept it.